# Slow C# iteration over model objects fetched from database

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, foreach

I am trying to fetch business model entities from database and then iterate them to search a string. However, in my localhost this operation takes approximately `7 to 9 seconds for 500 objects`.

```
public List<FileFolder> SearchFolders(int id, string searchString) 
{
    /* Placeholder that references folders that passes search criteria */
    List<FileFolder> addedFolders = new List<FileFolder>();

    /* Get the folder with specified id, also include Folders
     * that this folder has. No problem here works perfectly fine
     * and fast */
    FileFolder folder = dbSet.Include("Folders").
                             .Where(q => q.FileFolderID == id)
                             .ToList().FirstOrDefault();

    /* This takes too much time as I mention, up to 9 seconds
     * for 500 Folders */
    foreach (FileFolder f in folder.Folders)
    {
       if (f.Name.Contains(searchString))
       {
           addedFolders.Add(f);
       }

    }
    return addedFolders;
}
```

I am converting my fetched data to List so I can safely say all the data is now in memory? So foreach loop should not be making any more db calls while accessing folders. Also I have checked `.Include` method and it is is working fine.

What might be the cause of this slow iteration?

Thanks.

Comment: Its either ToList or FirstOrDefault. Why do you need both? Also why not use Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: I removed ToList thanks. Never used Parallel.ForEach, I ll consider it but is not it taking too much for just 500 objects ?

Comment: What are the specs of the machine this is executed?

Comment: Intel I7 Q740 1.7 GHZ and 8GB memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* This takes too much time as I mention, up to 9 seconds
 * for 500 Folders */
```

Remember, this is linq.  Things don't happen right away.  It does not actually start running the query before the first iteration of the `foreach()`.

What is really slow in this query is this

```
FileFolder folder = dbSet.Include("Folders").
                         .Where(q => q.FileFolderID == id)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

The real question is how is dbSet's "Folders" defined.  Do you have lots of FK joins built in?  If so a simple request like this can pull your whole database.  It all depends on what depends on "Folders".

You can even see this in the debugger, as you step over the foreach loop you will see it "pop" back to the linq line.

Comment: Actually, the code you pasted doesn't include the .ToList() that the OP's does.  The .ToList() will force the query execution, yes?  At least, it does in Linq 2 SQL.

Comment: @CB - of course it does, I must have looked at the wrong code.

Comment: Ahhh, like Dimitri's.  Totally.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this instead of Foreach:

```
    if (folder!=null)
       {
           addedFolders.AddRange(folder.Folders.Where(f=>f.Name.Contains(searchString)));
       }
```

The full code would look something like this:

```
public List<FileFolder> SearchFolders(int id, string searchString) 
{
    /* Placeholder that references folders that passes search criteria */
    List<FileFolder> addedFolders = new List<FileFolder>();

    /* Get the folder with specified id, also include Folders
     * that this folder has. No problem here works perfectly fine
     * and fast */
    FileFolder folder = dbSet.Include("Folders").
                             .Where(q => q.FileFolderID == id)
                             .FirstOrDefault();

    if (folder!=null)
    {
       addedFolders.AddRange(folder.Folders.Where(f=>f.Name.Contains(searchString)));
    }
    return addedFolders;
}
```

Comment: I have found that Linq is faster than iterations in some cases. So I suggested using it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your line:

```
foreach (FileFolder f in folder.Folders)
```

I'm guessing, but it looks like you have a single Folders table, where child folders are stored in the same table, with IDs linking back to parent IDs using a FK relationship?  If you have a deep folder hierarchy, you are probably ending up with a recursion issue as parents link to children, link to children, link to children, etc.  I don't know how EF (not terribly familiar with EF) would handle that, but my guess is that's where the issue lies.

Comment: yes my schema is exactly like that. However, my method does not run recursively, it only checks the folders of single folder.

Comment: I just wasn't sure if maybe the EF was trying to "help" you and doing something on its own.  It was my only guess as to why that particular loop is as crazy slow as it is.  Best of luck!